# How to query two types of records in CouchDB

Tags: asynchronous, couchdb, pouchdb, nosql

I’m having issues getting two dependant types of data from a PouchDB database.

I have a list of cars that I get like so:

```
localDB.query(function(doc) {
  if (doc.type === ‘list’) {
    emit(doc);
  }
}, {include_docs : true}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(“cars”, response);

  // Save Cars List to app
  for(var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
    addToCarsList(response.rows[i].id, response.rows[i].carNumber);
  }
  console.log(“Cars List: " + carsListToString());

  return response;

}).then(function(listRecord) {

  listRecord.rows.forEach(function(element, index){

    console.log(index + ' -> ', element);

    localDB.query(function(doc) {
      console.log("filtering with carNb = " + element.carNb);
      if (doc.type === 'defect' && doc.listId == getCurrentListId() && doc.carNb == element.carNb ) {
        emit(doc);
      }
    }, {include_docs : false}).then(function(result){
      console.log("defects", result);

    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log("an error has occurred", err);
    });
  });

}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('error', err);
});
```

Here's what happens. After getting the list of cars, then for each cars I would like to query the defects and store then in some arrays. Then when all that querying is done, I want to build the UI with the data saved.

But what's happening is that the forEach gets processed quickly and does not wait for the inner async'd localDb.query.

How can I query some documents based on an attribute from a parent query? I looked into promises in the PouchDB doc but I can't understand how to do it.

(please forget about curly quotes and possible lint errors, this code was anonymized by hand and ultra simplified)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (execute all promises and return when done).

However, your query is already pretty inefficient. It would be better to create a persistent index, otherwise it has to do a full database scan for every `query()` (!). You can read up on [the PouchDB query guide](http://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html) for details.

I would recommend installing the [pouchdb-upsert plugin](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-upsert) and then doing:

```
// helper method
function createDesignDoc(name, mapFunction) {
  var ddoc = {
    _id: '_design/' + name,
    views: {}
  };
  ddoc.views[name] = { map: mapFunction.toString() };
  return ddoc;
}

localDB.putIfNotExists(createDesignDoc('my_index', function (doc) {
  emit([doc.type, doc.listId, doc.carNb]);
})).then(function () {
  // find all docs with type 'list'
  return localDB.query('my_index', {
    startkey: ['list'],
    endkey: ['list', {}],
    include_docs: true
  });
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log("cars", response);

  // Save Cars List to app
  for(var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
    addToCarsList(response.rows[i].id, response.rows[i].carNumber);
  }
  console.log("Cars List: " + carsListToString());

  return response;
}).then(function (listRecord) {

  return PouchDB.utils.Promise.all(listRecord.rows.map(function (row) {
    // find all docs with the given type, listId, carNb
    return localDB.query('my_index', {
      key: ['defect', getCurrentListId(), row.doc.carNb],
      include_docs: true
    });
  }));
}).then(function (finalResults) {
  console.log(finalResults);
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log("an error has occurred", err);
});
```

I'm using a few tricks here:

- emit `[doc.type, doc.listId, doc.carNb]`, which allows us to query by type or by type+listId+carNb.
- when querying for just the type, we can do `{startkey: ['list'], endkey: ['list', {}]}`, which matches just those with the type "list" because `{}` is the "higher" than strings in CouchDB object collation order.
- `PouchDB.utils.Promise` is a "hidden" API, but it's pretty safe to use if you ask me. It's unlikely we'll change it.

**Edit** Another option is to use the new [pouchdb-find](http://nolanlawson.github.io/pouchdb-find/) plugin, which offers a simplified query API designed to replace the existing map/reduce `query()` API.

Comment: Had a bit of issue getting it to work but in the end it worked perfectly! :) Thanks! Also, I knew my code was not optimized, it was just a draft. I'm planning to add indexes once I get basic functionality in.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to pull both the list docs and the defect docs down at the same time then merge them together using a reduce like method that will convert them into an array of objects:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  type: 'list',
  ...
  defects: [{
    type: 'defect'
    listId: 1
    ...
  }]
}
```

By pulling the list and the defects down in one call you save a several calls to the pouchdb query engine, but you do have to iterate through every result to build your collection of lists objects with and embedded array of defects.

// This is untested code so it may not work, but you should get the idea
    var _ = require('underscore');

```
// order documents results by list then defect
var view = function (doc) {
  if (doc.type === 'list') {
    emit([doc._id, doc.carNumber, 1);
  } else if (doc.type === 'defect') {
    emit([doc.listId, doc.carNb, 2])
  }
}

localDB.query(view, { include_docs: true })
  .then(function(response) {
    return _(response.rows)
      .reduce(function(m, r) {
        if (r.key[2] === 1) {
          // initialize 
          r.doc.defects = [];
          m.push(r.doc)
          return m;
        }
        if (r.key[2] === 2) {
          var list = _(m).last()
          if (list._id === r.key[0] && list.carNumber === r.key[1]) {
            list.defects.push(r.doc);
          }
          return m;
        }
      }, []);  
  })
  .then(function(lists) {
    // bind to UI
  });
```

With couch, we found reducing calls to the couch engine to be more performant, but I don't know if this approach is better for PouchDB, but this should work as a solution, especially if you are wanting to embed several collections into one list document.

Comment: I have not tried your solution, but I will keep it in mind for my next page where I need two levels of data. Thanks!